# Logic to leave loop not working SAS

Tags: loops, sas

I want to repeat some code, varying one of the parameters and test whether a condition is met. If the condition is met, I want to leave the loop, if not I want to proceed to the next value of the parameter. I am using the below code, which works fine except that it does not leave the loop when I expect it to. Despite the summary showing that the condition should have been met it always seems to resolve to False.

```
%macro set_downward_caps(year, in_year_tolerance, large, small, start, end, increment);
%do c = &start. %to &end. %by &increment.;
    %let nominal_down_large_&year. = %sysevalf(&large. + (&c. / 1000));
    %let nominal_down_small_&year. = %sysevalf(&small. + (&c. / 100));
    %let real_down_large_&year. = %sysevalf((1 - &&nominal_down_large_&year.) * &&rpi&year.);
    %let real_down_small_&year. = %sysevalf((1 - &&nominal_down_small_&year.) * &&rpi&year.);
    %rates(&year.);
    proc means data = output.s_&scenario. noprint nway;
        var transbill&year.;
        output out = temporary (drop = _type_ _freq_) sum=cost;
    run;
    data _null_;
        set temporary;
        call symput('cost', cost);
    run;
    data temp;
        length scenario $ 30;
        scenario = "&scenario.";
        large = &&real_down_large_&year.;
        small = &&real_down_small_&year.;
        cost = &cost.;
    run;
    data output.summary_of_caps;
        set output.summary_of_caps temp;
    run;
    %if %sysfunc(abs(&cost.)) le &in_year_tolerance. %then leave;
%end;
%mend set_downward_caps;
```

So the sumary_of_caps table contains values that suggest that the following condition should have resolved to true:

```
%if %sysfunc(abs(&cost.)) le &in_year_tolerance. %then leave;
```

I've tried sticking it in sysevalf but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried setting the options MPRINT, MLOGIC and SYMBOLGEN?  This should help with identifying where the problem lies

Comment: Leave is only for datastep, not for macro. 
You can change this for example like this:
%if %sysfunc(abs(&cost.)) le &in_year_tolerance. %then %let c =%eval( &end.+ 1);

Comment: I had mlogic and mprint on. Will turn on symbolgen too.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestion to remove the leave. Unfortunately, I'm working from home today and sas works veeeery slowly.

Comment: If this was a data step I would suggest adding a while condition to the loop. Is that possible in a macro setting as well?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a `LEAVE` equivalent for macro code. Why not just use a `%GOTO`? Or since you seem to want to totally leave the macro you could use `%RETURN`.

Also if you are comparing floating point numbers you need to use `%SYSEVALF()`. The implied `%EVAL()` call of the `%IF` statement will only handle integer arithmetic.

```
%if %sysevalf(%sysfunc(abs(&cost)) le &in_year_tolerance) %then %return;
```

Why do the calculations in macro logic at all? I am not sure why you have all of those macro variables, unless the `%RATES()` macro is referencing them?  But if it needs them why aren't they parameters to the macro like you are passing in `&YEAR`?

You have plenty of data steps in your current code where you could do the calculation there and just set a flag variable that you can use to control whether to exit the loop.

```
%macro set_downward_caps
(year
,in_year_tolerance
,large
,small
,start
,end
,increment
);
%local c leave ;
%do c = &start %to &end %by &increment;
    %local nominal_down_large_&year ;
    %local nominal_down_small_&year ;
    %local real_down_large_&year ;
    %local real_down_small_&year ;

    %let nominal_down_large_&year. = %sysevalf(&large. + (&c. / 1000));
    %let nominal_down_small_&year. = %sysevalf(&small. + (&c. / 100));
    %let real_down_large_&year. = %sysevalf((1 - &&nominal_down_large_&year.) * &&rpi&year.);
    %let real_down_small_&year. = %sysevalf((1 - &&nominal_down_small_&year.) * &&rpi&year.);

    %rates(&year.);

    proc means data = output.s_&scenario. noprint nway;
        var transbill&year.;
        output out = temporary sum=cost;
    run;

    data temp;
        length scenario $ 30;
        scenario = "&scenario.";
        large = &&real_down_large_&year.;
        small = &&real_down_small_&year.;
        set temporary (keep=cost);
        call symputx('leave',abs(cost) le &in_year_tolerance);
        put (_all_) (=);
    run;
    data output.summary_of_caps;
        set output.summary_of_caps temp;
    run;
    %if (&leave) %then %goto quit;
%end;
%quit:
%mend set_downward_caps;
```

Comment: What are the values of the macro variables COST and IN_YEAR_TOLERANCE?

Comment: I have isolated the problem. SAS is treating cost and in year tolerance as char vars. Don't know how to fix it though...

Comment: Do not use the old `CALL SYMPUT()` function. Use the new `CALL SYMPUTX()` function as it will automatically remove the leading spaces. Also if your numbers are large then with either you might need to use your own format instead of the default `BEST12.` format.  `call symputX('cost',put(cost,best32.));`

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, no change.